# Flot JS turn target into diamond shape

Tags: javascript, flot

I've three series of data: for green bars, red bard and target like

```
var dataBarsRed = {
    data: [
        [2, 3], ],
    label: 'Bars in Red',
    color: 'red'
};
var dataBarsGreen = {
    data: [
        [1, 2],
        [3, 1],
        [4, 3]
    ],
    label: 'Bars in Green',
    color: 'green'
};
var dataLines = {
    data: [
        [1, 3, 3],
        [2, 3.5, 3.5],
        [3, 1.5, 1.5],
        [4, 2.5, 2.5]
    ],
    label: 'Lines',
    color: 'navy',
    bars: {
        barWidth: 0.5
    }
};
```

I've attached the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6cn7tgps/) for it. 
It is possible to make the target as diamond ([image: this]) using Flot JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize the point shape by specifying it in the series options (or each individual series). The [symbol plugin](https://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/symbols/index.html) can be used access more shapes:

```
var options = {
    series: {
        points: {
            shape: "diamond"
        }
    }
}
```

This [updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a4xu13q2/) uses the symbols plugin to show diamonds as the point marker.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that :)